# Reoccurring local notification for UTC time

Tags: swift, datetime, uilocalnotification

I looked all over stack overflow and was only able to find reoccurring local notifications for a specific time. However, I am trying to find information on how to make a reoccurring local notification based off a UTC time. The reason behind when you set up a reoccurring notification, it will stay to that specific time.

For example, at the moment 00:00:00 UTC is 5pm eastern time but when day light savings hits in a few months, the new time will be 4pm. However, the reoccurring notification is still set to 5pm. So this notification is now one hour off because of day light savings.

I am trying to figure out how to accomplish this, so the local notification will move properly with day light savings. I am not sure if this is possible since the reoccurring is set to a specific time, but I would love to find more information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default current Time Zone is considered for delivering local notifications. To use UTC time while registering for local notification, you need to set Time Zone to UTC.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

//get the notification center
let center =  UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

//create the content for the notification
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = " Title"
content.subtitle = "SubTitle"
content.body = "jvsvsvasvbasbvfasfv"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

var dateComp = DateComponents()
dateComp.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC") // set time zone to UTC
dateComp.day = 1;
dateComp.hour = 08;
dateComp.minute = 00;

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComp, repeats: true)

//create request to display
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "ContentIdentifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)

//add request to notification center
center.add(request) { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

Above code sets notification every morning 8 am UTC time.

Comment: I see, so my mistake was trying to convert to local time when I should have been setting it to utc in the first place. That way, it will change properly with the day light savings. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Ah, thank you. I guess I had an incorrect understanding. Thanks for the clarification